# Instagram Feed Crashes my app: access_token invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, instagram-api

I'm using the [Instagram gem](https://github.com/facebookarchive/instagram-ruby-gem) to access the Instagram API to pull in a feed of images into out website footer. This code has been working fine for several months, and yesterday I got an error 400: The access_token provided is invalid. I had to go in and change my access_token to get the site working again.

I'm wondering what would be the best way to abstract this and make it a background task so that it doesn't crash my site when there are issues with the receiving data from Instagram's API.

Here's my code:
Instagram.rb Initializer

```
require "instagram"

  Instagram.configure do |config|

  config.client_id = [client_id]

  config.access_token = [access_token]

end
```

Application Controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :set_instagram
  private
    def set_instagram
      @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media('user_id', {:count => 9})
    end
end
```

View page:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 column4">
  <h5><%= t( '.instagram' )%></h5>
  <div class="insta-box flickr-feed" >
    <% @instagram.each do |instagram| %>    
      <a href='<%= instagram.link %>' target="_blank"><%= image_tag instagram.images.standard_resolution.url, alt: instagram.caption.text  %></a>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Like I said, the code works fine now, but I'm trying to find a way to prevent future crashes from happening through either creating a background job (I use sidekiq) or in a less ideal situation saving the the most recent Instagram images to a database table each time a new one comes through.